# Compare an array with the database

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I store in a MySql database the hours that the customers have taken. Now I want to show in a web all the hours (and half the hour) in order from 9, 9,30, 10, 10,30... And show which hours are taken and witch are free. The code here works only I there is one hour in the database. If I have two hours in the database in the web it repeats all the hours twice, if I have 3 hours in the database it repeats 3 times... For instance I have in the database 9:00:00 and 10:00:00, the fist time it gives the 9 in red, the second time it gives only the 10 in red:        09:00:00","09:30:00","10:00:00","10:30:00
09:00:00","09:30:00","10:00:00","10:30:00

I do not understand what is wrong? how can I have all the ours in order and just one time?

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM consulta
                  WHERE professional=1
                  AND client=0');
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

// 1- put the hours in a array:
$hours = array("09:00:00","09:30:00","10:00:00","10:30:00"); 

// 2- give each element of the array the var $hour
foreach ($hours as $hour) 
{  
    // 3- check each element of the array with each element of de database:
    if ($row['hora'] == $hour) {
        // hour was found in the database
        echo '<p style="color:blue;">'. $hour .'</p>';
    } else { 
        // hour was not found
        echo '<p style="color:red;">'. $hour .'</p>';
    }
}// end foreach

} // end while
```

In this example if I `echo $row['hora'] . '<br>';` it gives me:
09:00:00
10:00:00

Comment: Your code seems fine to me. If I substitute your times with simple integers and compare that with a table of integers, output is exactly as expected. It works with strings too!

Comment: Ah, except I think you're iterating through both arrays in their entirety each time!

Answer (score 0):

your code seems good. If you want, you can to try another solution:

$result = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM consulta WHERE professional=1 AND cliente=0');

```
// var_dump($result);
$hours = array("09:00:00","09:30:00","10:00:00","10:30:00");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
if (in_array($row['hora'], $hours)) 
    {
        echo '<p style="color:blue;">'.$row['hora'] .'</p>';
    }
    else{
        echo '<p style="color:red;">'. $row['hora'] .'</p>';
    }
}
```

second version:

```
//imprime todos los elementos presentes en array $hours    
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $rows[] = $row['hora'];
    }
    foreach ($hours as $hour) {
            if (in_array($hour, $rows))
            {
                echo '<p style="color:blue;">'.$hour .'</p>';
            }
            else{
                echo '<p style="color:red;">'. $hour .'</p>';

            }
    }
```

Comment: It gives me an error: Array to string conversion in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/trobadaVirtual/reserva-calendari/3/9.1.php on line 43 Array  The while is not necessary here?

Comment: try while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  instead of foreach ($result as $row )

Comment: Perhaps I could convert the results of the database in an array. I think now, they are not. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: this only gives the hours that are in the database not all the hours

Answer (score 0):

Well, to be sure, you could convert the 'time' field to char, and then remove all the ':' from the rows, and check for matches again.

From my experience, I had problems on comparing 'date' fields, because of my server location (Brazil), and as I can see, you are from here too.

Hope it helps.

edit:

Also, remove the `$hours` array from the `while` loop, and remove the ':' from them also.

Comment: I am not sure If I understand. How do I convert the time field to char?. By the way I am from Andorra (small nation in Europe) and I have not heard of any problems with the server?

Comment: My bad, then. Well, it depends, is this database you're using a production database, or a development database?

Comment: I am using Mamp in local